# java- adding an element to a list in an existing XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, nodelist

I have a list of "lineItems" that contains "lineItem" elements, i have it in different places in the XML.
My question is as follows:
How do i add a "lineItem" element in the specific path that i want?
e.g.

```
<GroupA>
    <Name> </Name>
    <LineItems>
        <LineItem>
            <Age></Age>
            <Description> </Description>
            <Address> </Address>
            <Type></Type>
            <Name> </Name>
        </LineItem>
        <LineItem>
            <Age></Age>
            <Description> </Description>
            <Address> </Address>
            <Type></Type>
            <Name> </Name>
        </LineItem>
    </LineItems>
</GroupA>


<GroupB>
    <Section>
        <GroupOfPpls>
            <GroupOfPpl>
                <TypeOfCharges></TypeOfCharges>
                <Name> </Name>
                <LineItems>
                    <LineItem>
                        <Age> </Age>
                        <Description> </Description>
                        <Address> </Address>
                        <Type> </Type>
                        <Name> </Name>
                    </LineItem>   
                </LineItems>
            </GroupOfPpl>   
        </GroupOfPpls>
    </Section>
    </GroupB>
```

Im using xpath and nodeList in my code. cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM and add the node. You can use XPath to get the parent node .[see here for a code](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/)

Comment: But how do i tell him the specific path?